# For c = 3 find the complete solution $x$ to $Ax = \begin{bmatrix}1\\c\\0\end{bmatrix} $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

the matrix is: $$\color{green}{ \begin{bmatrix}1&1&2&4\\3&c&2&8\\0&0&2&2\end{bmatrix} }\cdot$$

reducing the matrix gives me:
$$\color{green}{ \begin{bmatrix}1&1&2&4\\0&c-3&-4&-4\\0&0&2&2\end{bmatrix} }\cdot$$

I already calculated the solution for the nullspace of A

$$\color{green}{ \begin{bmatrix}-2\\0\\-1\\1\end{bmatrix} }\cdot$$

the solution is one vector + the solution for the nullspace help me find that first vector by inspection

Comment: Notice that $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ c \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ is the second column of $A$. The one vector is then :
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
The nullspace is spanned by :
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \text{ and} \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\begin {pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\end {pmatrix} $ works nicely as a particular solution, and the solution set is thus $$\{\begin {pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\end {pmatrix}+s\cdot \begin {pmatrix}-2\\0\\-1\\1\end {pmatrix}+t\cdot \begin {pmatrix}1\\-1\\0\\0\end {pmatrix}\mid s,t\in\Bbb F\}$$.

That's the null space is actually $\color{red}2$-dimensional.